# Linear functional as the trace of a positive semidefinite operator

Tags: linear-algebra

The following relation is used in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.69.022308) (Theorem 1) as a "well-known result" (here slightly edited):

> Let $F_\rho$ be a linear functional on convex combinations of positive
> states in $\mathcal{H}$ (where a "state" $\rho$ is a positive
> semidefinite operator with $\text{tr}{\rho}=1$, and $\mathcal{H}$ a
> finite-dimensional Hilbert space).
>
> Since $F_\rho$ is defined on a basis, there is a unique way of
> extending this functional linearly to the whole space of operators in
> $\mathcal{H}$. So we have a linear, positive and continuous functional
> on a finite dimensional Hilbert space, and it is a well-known result
> that any such functional can be written as
>
> $$F_\rho(b) = \text{tr}(\sigma_\rho b) \;\;\forall b$$
> for some unique positive semidefinite operator $\sigma_\rho$ in $\mathcal{H}$.

Can someone point me to a reference on this result? I am particularly interested in *which* operator would the unique $\sigma_\rho$ be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do use subscript $\rho $ in $F$ ? From what you write I understand that $F$ is a linear functional on $B(\mathcal{H})$ - the space of all linear operators from $\mathcal H$ to $\mathcal H,$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is finite dimensional euclidean space. Choose an orthonormal basis $\{v_j\}$ in $\mathcal{H}.$ Denote by $E_{ij} $ the operator acting by the rule $E_{ij}(x)=\langle x,v_j\rangle v_i.$ Then
$$F(E_{ij})={\rm tr}\, \sigma E_{ij}=\sum_k \langle \sigma E_{ij}v_k,v_k\rangle  \\ =\sum _k \langle E_{ij} v_k, \sigma^* v_k\rangle =\langle v_i, \sigma^* v_j\rangle =\langle \sigma v_i, v_j\rangle $$
Hence
$$\sigma=\sum_i\sum_j F(E_{ji}) E_{ij}$$